# Lambda python 3.7 : Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Dimensions[0]

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have been getting this error for days and unable to sort out whats the issues on this code:

```
"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Dimensions[0].Value, value: {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'str'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 26, in bucket_size\n    Unit='Bytes'\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 320, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 596, in _make_api_call\n    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 632, in _convert_to_request_dict\n    api_params, operation_model)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py\", line 291, in serialize_to_request\n    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\n"
  ]
```

### My python 3.7 code:

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json


def bucket_size(a, b):
    bucket_name = a
    cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch',region_name='ap-southeast-1')
    response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace="AWS/S3",
        MetricName="BucketSizeBytes",
        Dimensions=[
            {
                'Name': 'BucketName',
                'Value': bucket_name
            },
            {
                'Name': 'StorageType',
                'Value': 'StandardStorage'
            }
        ],
        Statistics=['Average'],
        Period=86400,
        StartTime=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=10),
        EndTime=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=2),
        Unit='Bytes'
    )
```

---

i am trying to get the metric from S3 and pipe to a .csv file on specific S3 bucket, but i encounter this error on lambda python 3.7

Any help appreciated, open alot of tabs to find answers online but not available, thanks and appreciated ! Cheers

Comment: You're passing a dictionary in `a` (or so says the error message) which in turn passes a dictionary as `'Value'` in the first dictionary in the list.

Comment: Please show us the code that is calling this function.

Comment: i am using lambda with test events:

{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}

Comment: i will only trigger this every month end to generate the volume size of each individual s3 bucket, but i got stucked here at the get_metric_statistics.
Ironically i can load this python code successfully with exit code 0 in my pycharm CE though

Comment: @ak86 the test event should be a string, not a dict, most likely a JSON that would then be loaded into a dict.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but i think is on

```
Dimensions=[
            {
                'Name': 'BucketName',
                'Value': bucket_name
            },
            {
                'Name': 'StorageType',
                'Value': 'StandardStorage'
            }
        ]
```

You are passing a list of dicts objects and module is expecting a list of string objects.